# why I got mixed file path separators?

Tags: python

I am using windows 10 with jupyter notebook under annaconda.

```
last_file = glob('../inputs/transactions_all/transactions*.xlsx')[-1] # path to file in the folder
last_file

'../inputs/transactions_all\\transactions_finaldf_2021-05-15_12h19m_repo.xlsx'
```

from the above, I got `/` and `\\` for path separators? I am expecting the result like this

```
'..\inputs\transactions_all\transactions_finaldf_2021-05-15_12h19m_repo.xlsx'
```

How can I modify my codes to get above results?

Comment: iirc glob uses `"{directory}{os.sep}{file}"` as its output format. In which case the directory, as given, is `'../inputs/transactions_all'`, and `os.sep` is of course `\ ` because you're on windows. Have you considered simply writing the initial url with `\ `, or doing `str.replace(last_file, '/', '\\')`?

Comment: It doesn't matter one little bit.  ALL Windows APIs accept either forward or backward slashes.  If it really bothers you aesthetically, you can use `replace` to change them.

Comment: after you found the file, you can use `pathlib.Path` to get the slashes right. something like
```from pathlib import Path``` and then `last_file_path = Path(last_file)`

Comment: Why not simply change the separators in the glob? `'..\\inputs\\transactions_all\\transactions*.xlsx'`

Comment: I see, for windows, I am supposed to write like this last_file = glob('..\\inputs\\transactions_all\\transactions*.xlsx')[-1]. Then it will use only \\. Thanks

Comment: @Green FWIW I skimmed the source code and found [two lines that use `os.path.join()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/94483f1e3cec182fabe19268e579f63045bc984a/Lib/glob.py#L86-L87)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no problem working with either \ or /, python know how to work with those (in windows at least), that being said if you want to ensure the correct one you can use [normcase](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.normcase)

```
>>> import os
>>> p='../inputs/transactions_all\\transactions_finaldf_2021-05-15_12h19m_repo.xlsx'
>>> os.path.normcase(p)
'..\\inputs\\transactions_all\\transactions_finaldf_2021-05-15_12h19m_repo.xlsx'
>>>
```

You can also use the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module to handle your paths that way they always will be the appropriate one for the OS you are working on